# iOS AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperationManager not setting json headers?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Im using AFNetworking

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'

I need to send a POST with json headers, but its going out as

"Content-Type" = "text/html";

Why??, please see in  my code im setting this?

```
- (void)postRequestWithParams:(NSDictionary*)paramasDicto andURL:(NSString*)url
                      success:(void (^)(id responseObject))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager
     POST:url
     parameters:paramasDicto
     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

     } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         success(responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         failure(error);
         DLog(@"error : %@", error);
     }];
}
```

please note that if i do: po manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders

I get

```
{
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "OrderingShopPhone/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in [the relevant AFNetworking code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m) could possibly set `text/html`.

Possible explanations:

- You're changing it somewhere else in your code before it goes out
- You have an intermediary server that's changing the request after it leaves your app (for example, your load balancer might be overwriting it).

Side note: there have been lots of important bug fixes since version 2.2; you should update to 2.3.1, although I don't think it'll fix this issue.